# Automate data upload to Google Cloud Storage and BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to transfer some data from my app to Big Query so I can then run SQL queries on it. Below are the steps I'm taking and wondering if there is a tool to automate this process.

1. Manually download data from app from terminal which is in JSON format.
2. Run python script to parse this file into readable JSON and make modifications (e.g. replace spaces with underscores etc. to be able to upload to Google Cloud Storage (GCS).
3. Manually upload this updated file to GCS.
4. Use this data from GCS to manually generate dataset and tables in Big Query using a schema.

Is there a way to automate this whole process using a cloud tool? I looked into Google Dataflow but it doesn't seem to be the tool for this. Or should I just have a python program that does all of the above?

Please advise.

Comment: What the size of your file? From where are you downloading your file? From the public internet?

Comment: Size of file is pretty small at this point still testing stuff out. Database has only about 1000 rows max for now. It is downloaded from a mobile app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your issue, I will write 3 services (Cloud Functions or Cloud Run for example. It's serverless, pay as you use, and with the free tiers, and your volume you will pay nothing at the end).

- Service 1: download the file and store it on Cloud Storage as raw file
- Service 2: get the file from storage, transform the file and store it back to storage as clean file
- Service 3: Load data in BigQuery.

Here the process in event driven architecture:

- Create a cloud scheduler that call your Service 1 when you need to download the file (once a day, once by hour,...)
- When the raw file is stored in Cloud Storage, an event is emitted. Catch it to trigger your Service 2 (there are 2 manners to achieve that, if you don't know how, let me know)
- When the clean file is stored in Cloud Storage, an event is emitted. Catch it to trigger your Service 3

You can also achieve the same thing by orchestration, with Cloud Workflow

- Deploy your workflow on Cloud Workflow
- Create a cloud scheduler that call your Workflow when you need to download the file (once a day, once by hour,...)
- Let the workflow running:

  - Call the service 1.
  - When service 1 is over, call service 2
  - When service 2 is over, call service 3

---

To start, you can perform all the action of the 3 services in the same service. It's easier for a POC. But for the scalability and the evolution of your solution, it's a better design to limit the responsibility of each service.

---

**EDIT 1**

To catch the event from Cloud Storage you have several solutions

- If you use Cloud Functions, you can [plug it directly on GCS event](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage). *It's named a background function*
- If you use http Cloud Functions or Cloud Run, you can [publish the Cloud Storage events in PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications). Then, on PubSub, you can create a [push subscription to call an HTTP endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) (the http Cloud Functions or Cloud Run). Take care of the security here. if you are stuck, ask me again. *It's my preferred and the most universal solution*
- If you use Cloud Run, you can also use [Eventarc](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/quickstarts) to catch the Storage event and call the Cloud Run service. *EventArc wraps the previous solution for you in a "one click deployment"*

Comment: Can you direct me on triggering events? Is this like Lambda functions in AWS? Also anywhere I can read up on exact procedure would be helpful. I'm quite new to cloud services. Have only used some from AWS, none from Google.

Comment: So all I need is Google Cloud Scheduler or Cloud Workflow?

Comment: Cloud Scheduler is required to start the process regularly, either to call your service 1, or to run a Workflow execution.

Comment: And these 3 services will be GCS event triggers, correct?

Comment: No, only the 2 and the 3. The 1, the download the file, it's trigger by an API Call (Cloud Scheduler, or Cloud Workflow)

Comment: Hello, can I DM you for some guidance?

Comment: You can reach me on twitter or on linkedin.

Comment: I sent you an invite.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about apache airflow and the google cloud version of this framework : composer. You can set up a workflow with each task is a step you mentioned.
Airflow supports a lot of operators: BashOperator, PythonOperator, BigQuery,...